# no such option: --rosdep-install

Tags: ros, rosdep-install

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have been trying to build pi_vision package with no success. I have been following the steps explained on: 3w.ros.org/wiki/pi_face_tracker

I have downloaded the source to one of the folders which is specified on the environment variable $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

The problem is whenever I run the command:
rosmake --rosdep-install pi_vision

An error message is output to console as follows:
"
Usage: rosmake [options] [PACKAGE]...

rosmake: error: no such option: --rosdep-install
".

How can I solve this problem?

Best regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49065/no-such-option:---rosdep-install/) by [enienws](https://answers.ros.org/users/3668/enienws/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The instructions lag a bit behind the development of tools, making it difficult ( I have lots of problems with it as well).
But rosdep is now a standalone tool. So I think you should use rosdep install pi_vision or rosdep install uvc_cam

Edit: Both do not seem to work...

```
rosdep install uvc_cam
failed to load symbols, rosdep will not function properly
Cannot import rospkg, rosdep will not function properly
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/rosdep", line 3, in <module>
   from rosdep2.main import rosdep_main
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/main.py", line 50, in <module>
   from .lookup import RosdepLookup, ResolutionError
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/lookup.py", line 41, in <module>
    from .rospkg_loader import RosPkgLoader
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/rospkg_loader.py", line 37, in <module>
    import catkin_pkg.package
ImportError: No module named catkin_pkg.package
```

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2012-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2012-11-26**:
Instacll python-catkin-pkg for this problem

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2012-11-26**:
Else this response is right, I changed the wiki instructions accordingly

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2012-11-26**:
Thanks, but for me it stil does not work, I did rosdep install pi_vision and then: rosmake
Finding dependencies for /home/lennart/fuerte_workspace/pi_vision/cfg/UVCCam.cfg

load_module did not return. Unable to de

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2012-11-26**:
Thanks, but for me it stil does not work: